# How can you tell what generator an iterator is for in ES6?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-harmony

In the following:

```
function *bar() {
    console.log( yield 1 );
    console.log( yield 2 );
    console.log( "done" );
}
var it = bar();
it.next();

it2 = fromTheTop(it); 
function fromTheTop(it){
   // ???
}
```

How could you write the `fromTheTop` function to create a new iterator for the same source as `it` came?
Notice, I'm not trying to clone the argument, so other questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179693/how-to-clone-es6-generator) are not quite right. I'm new to generators in JS, so maybe it's just a matter of phrasing the question ? TIA !

Comment: If you enumerate an iterator twice, I think all bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* that information (where it came from) is available from an iterator. At least, I'm not [seeing anything to suggest it is](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-iteration).