# Are JavaScript generators copyable / cloneable?

Tags: javascript

I am writing tests for a generator function that walks a tree.  The `next` function accepts a boolean to determine if it should continue to explore that branch of the tree.
I would like to be able to test it as follows:

```js
let tree_walker = make_tree_walking_generator(some_arguments)

let result = tree_walker.next()
test(result.value, "0", "Test it returns root element")

// I assume this is not possible yet / ever?
let tree_walker_clone = clone_generator_and_state(tree_walker) // <--

result = tree_walker.next(true) // true === first element was consumed (i.e. it was all that was needed)
test(result.value, undefined, "Test it returns undefined if last element was consumed")
test(result.done, true) // should be finished

// Restore the original state captured in the clone
tree_walker = tree_walker_clone
result = tree_walker.next(false) // false === first element was not consumed
test(result.value, "0->1", "Test it returns the next element if the last element was not consumed")
test(result.done, false) // should not be finished
```

This is important because otherwise you have to call the generator again with all the same arguments, e.g.:

```js
// get the same starting generator again
tree_walker = make_tree_walking_generator(some_arguments)
// Bring it back up to the same penultimate position (n-1)
result = tree_walker.next()
// Continue testing from this point.  The problem is the previous
// call is made twice and for a deep tree this might be many 10s of
// calls with complex arguments.

result = tree_walker.next(false) // false === first element was not consumed
test(result.value, "0->1", "Test it returns the next element if the last element was not consumed")
test(result.done, false) // should not be finished
```

An alternatively to some cloning function would be the ability to rewind a generator.  A second alternative is to write a wrapper that records all of the arguments and (**assuming the generator is pure**) can replay the last n-1 arguments to get a generator in the previous state.

Comment: Thank you @DimaParzhitsky :) I've corrected it.

Comment: Not sure why you would need a clone of a generator. I never saw a stateful generator in practice (not counting closure as a state), so just creating the same generator again would suffice

Comment: `let tree_walker = make(args); let tree_walker_clone = make(args);`

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: Thanks @DimaParzhitsky unfortunately not as in that example we would also need to call: `tree_walker_clone.next()` to get it back to the same state.  I've elaborated the question's example so hopefully that helps explain it better?

Comment: I see. Looks like generators are a wrong tool for the job

Comment: Perhaps, for now I am still viewing it as a more general question of "How do you test advanced generators?" which allow branching logic / state.

Comment: "*A second alternative is to write a wrapper that records all of the arguments and can replay the last n-1 arguments to get a generator in the previous state.*" - yes, that's what you'll need to do