# How to clear current position for Iterable object when using next()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I clear the current position after the for loop or after I used `.next()`  method ?

```
 const arr = [1,4,2];
 for(v of arr){
     // console.log(v); // 1 4 2
 }
 //  console.log(arr.next())  //arr.next is not a function

 /*
 * 
 * Why? because it is an iterable not an iterator,
 * and to be able to use .next we need to call the iterator method 
 * this iterable’s Symbol.iterator returns:
 * */
 const iter = arr[Symbol.iterator]();

 console.log(iter.next());
 console.log(iter.next());
 console.log(iter.next());
 console.log(iter.next());
```

After this I want get 1 value from item.

How to do this ?

This example is from http://blog.dubizzle.com/boilerroom/2017/01/09/introduction-javascript-iterables-iterators-generators/

Comment: What do you mean by _"clear current position"_?

Comment: do you like to get the values ad infinitum?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to 'clear the current position' per se. However, helpful alternatives were suggested in this answer: [Is it possible to reset an ECMAScript 6 generator to its initial state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848113/is-it-possible-to-reset-an-ecmascript-6-generator-to-its-initial-state).

Comment: Iterator.return is not a function