# Is it possible to compose generator functions like you would normal functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator, iterable

Question:
Is it possible to compose two generators into one generator like you would with `compose`?

```
function* type(vals) {
  for(const v of vals) {
    yield v;
  }
}

const bool = type([true, false]);
const str = type([
  '',
  undefined,
  'Lorem',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
  ''
]);

const composeGenerator = () => {/*???*/};  
const input = composeGenerator(bool,str);
console.log(input, 'yes');

for (const i of bool) {
  console.log(i); // true, false
}

for (const i of str) {
  console.log(i); // '',  undefined,  'Lorem',  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',  ''
}

for (const i of input) {
  console.log(i); // '',  undefined,  'Lorem',  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',  '', true, false
}
```

Comment: Also your expected output is in the order of `[...str, ...bool]` but your parameters are in the order `bool, str`. Was that intentional?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts either order is fine... compose is right to let sometimes. but Im indifferent

Comment: In function composition, you pass the result of one function as an argument to the other. Your generator functions do not take any arguments though, so this doesn't make any sense? Your desired output (the `input` iterable) looks much more like a simple **concatenation**.

Comment: You can simply concatenate generators or any iterables with [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `type` function can actually be shortened, first of all. Secondly, here's one possible implementation of your `composeGenerator` from left to right:

```js
function * type (iterable) {
  yield * iterable;
}

const bool = type([true, false]);
const str = type([
  '',
  undefined,
  'Lorem',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
  ''
]);

function * composeGenerator (...iterables) {
  for (const iterable of iterables) yield * iterable;
}

const input = composeGenerator(str, bool);

for (const i of input) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: if you made bool and str functions like const bool = () => type ([true, false]) they could be excuted again right?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood no, that's not right. If you want to unaccept my answer go ahead, but doing that is not trivial. You'd have to modify the objects you accepted as input, which could lead to complicated and unexpected behavior.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/matthewharwood/b722988116afc8eb79a8321a3e940eee no it did work but maybe I didn't explain it  @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @MatthewHarwood actually I think I misread your first comment. Should I edit my answer to address how you'd be able to re-use your curried functions?

Comment: Yeah go ahead lets do that! also if your down round 2 is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105848/write-a-fn-loop-that-iterate-over-a-generator-that-has-inner-generators

Comment: @MatthewHarwood Ah nevermind, I guess I don't need to edit. I need to work on reading comments better apparently. Yes it does work the way you expected it to when encapsulating in higher order functions.

Answer (score 0):

We iterate over all generators until they yield a value

```js
function* type(vals) {
  for(const v of vals) {
    yield v;
  }
}

const bool = type([true, false]);
const str = type([
  '',
  undefined,
  'Lorem',
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
  ''
]);

function *composeGenerator(...iterators) {
  for (const iterator of iterators) {
    for (const value of iterator ) {
      yield value;
    }
  }
}

const input = composeGenerator(bool,str);

for (const i of input) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: The question showed that `bool` and `str` were iterated prior to iterating `input`. This wouldn't work in the example code provided.

Comment: I think that was shown for demonstrative purposes only.

Comment: One would have to reset the iterators if they want to iterate over them again (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848113/is-it-possible-to-reset-an-ecmascript-6-generator-to-its-initial-state) (and the question is here about composition)